# Longest possible combined CC duration In League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

What's the longest time a team of five players can hard-CC (stunned etc.) a single enemy champion continuously by chaining their CC?

Comment: There are a lot of characters with stun. The question itself is purely theoretical. If you take Amumu: 2s, Veigar: 3s, Ashe: 3.5, Leona: 1.25 + 1.5s, Braum: 1.75s for example, your up for 13 seconds of stuns. By that time you will probably have died at least twice to the associated damage.

Comment: @M'vy Nothing wrong with purely theoretical questions. They're fun.

Comment: Having a CC on the river, if the river camp is on your team, doubles the CC duration. Check for more info ingame/wiki.

Comment: I think hard CC refers to effects that prevent moving, attacking, and using abilities. Rooting doesn't count.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the wiki, there's 4 types of hard [crowd control](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_control): airborne, forced action, stun, and suppression.

Assuming max CDR and level 18:

```
                          cost per      cost/
Champ        cc  secs cd  stun     mp5  mp10
--------------------------------------------------
Brand        q+w 2    3.6 140      18.2 3.9
Thresh       q   1.5  4.2 80       19.6 2.2
Xerath       e   2.25 6.6 80       19.6 2.2
Fiddlesticks q   2.25 6.6 65       19.6 1.8
Elise        e   2    6   50       19.6 1.4
```

So, if each champ chains their cc once, the target will be stunned for 10 seconds. After 10 seconds, all of the abilities will be off cooldown, so we only need to worry about mana. Dividing the champ's stun cost by the champ's MP10 gives us the percentage mana regen needed to recoup the stun's cost in the 10 second window. Brand's is the worst, at 3.9. Base mana regen + Morellonomicon + Mikael's crucible + Talisman gives brand 400%, which covers the mana needed.

Therefore, it is possible to infinitely chain hard cc on a single champ, given the right champs and items.

Comment: How does this scale if the champion being CC'd has max tenacity? ;)

Comment: Leaving aside Olaf's ult, Irelia with max passive stacks, Merc's Threads and Elixir of Iron adds up to what, `1 - (0.6 * 0.65 * 0.65) = 74%` reduction?

Comment: Just an aside, these numbers are from patch 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Indefinite.

For simplicity's sake we'll just use a team of 5 Lux. Lux Q (binding light, roots enemy for 2 seconds) has an 11 second CD maxed out. With 40% CDR that's a 6.6 CD. Rooting lasts for 2 seconds. Only 4 Luxes are needed for perma CC.

Obviously, with other champions that have multiple CCs, low CD CCs, etc, infinite CC is definitely possible.

In a real match, the way the game works, death or CC evasion is much more likely to happen than a really long CC chain.

EDIT: 
Okay, here's a full example.

We can have the target stand next to the enemy nexus so mana won't be an issue. This setup would only require 4 people.

```
Lux - 6.6 CD 2 CC
Morgana - 6.6 CD 3 CC
Udyr - 6 CD 1 CC
Leona 4.2 CD 1.25 CC
```

Comment: They don't have infinite mana, also, normal game modes don't feature five of the same champ, even if it's just an example.

Comment: edited with example. mana wont be an issue next to nexus

Answer (score -2):

zilean ABOUT 30 sec with E Q W E Q W E Q W E Q W E Q W E Q W E Q W E COMBO Do those CC chains come even close to this?
Zilean CD 22 CC 29.5

Comment: His Q has a 8s CD (4.4s at 45%cdr) and the E has a 6s CD (3.3s at 45% cdr). Zillean can only stun if he connects 2 bombs. Zillean's bombs detonate after 3 seconds, meaning that it's impossible for him to throw a Q->Q-> combo. This means he needs to have both his Q and E up in order to use Q->E (resets Q) -> Q. With that said, then he can keep a target stunned for 1.5s every 4.4s (if you ignore reaction, animation and casting times). As per Arkive's answer, he wouldn't make the "perma cc" team